# how to bookmark and delete the line for multiple files

Tags: batch-file

I want to book mark and delete the lines from the multiple XML files. I'm new to batch file programming. Could any one pls help me to create the batch file which should read the file and delete the line which contains the string.

Eg: Below is the content of one XML file in which i want to delete the lines which contains "cimage.gif" and "appcover".

```
  <file>/cimages/ncomms_cimage.jpg</file>
  <file>/ncomms/2014/141223/ncomms6646/abs/ncomms6646.html</file>
  <file>/ncomms/2014/141223/ncomms6646/carousel/ncomms6646-f1.jpg</file>
  <file>/ncomms/2014/141223/ncomms6646/carousel/ncomms6646-f2.jpg</file>
  <file>/ncomms/2014/141223/ncomms6646/carousel/ncomms6646-f3.jpg</file>
  <file>/ncomms/2014/141223/ncomms6646/carousel/ncomms6646-f4.jpg</file>
  <file>/ncomms/2014/141223/ncomms6646/carousel/ncomms6646-f5.jpg</file>
  <file>/ncomms/2014/141223/ncomms6646/carousel/ncomms6646-f6.jpg</file>
  <file>/ncomms/2014/141223/ncomms6646/compound/ncomms6646_ci.html</file>
  <file>/ncomms/2014/141223/ncomms6646/covers/appcover-ncomms-v5-ncomms6646-150x193.png</file>
  <file>/ncomms/2014/141223/ncomms6646/covers/appcover-ncomms-v5-ncomms6646-450x579.png</file>
  <file>/ncomms/2014/141223/ncomms6646/covers/appcover-ncomms-v5-ncomms6646-75x100.png</file>
  <file>/ncomms/2014/141223/ncomms6646/extref/ncomms6646-s1.pdf</file>
  <file>/ncomms/2014/141223/ncomms6646/extref/ncomms6646-s2.xls</file>
  <file>/ncomms/2014/141223/ncomms6646/extref/ncomms6646-s3.xls</file>
  <file>/ncomms/2014/141223/ncomms6646/extref/ncomms6646-s4.avi</file>
  <file>/ncomms/2014/141223/ncomms6646/fig_tab/ncomms6646_F1.html</file>
  <file>/ncomms/2014/141223/ncomms6646/fig_tab/ncomms6646_F2.html</file>
  <file>/ncomms/2014/141223/ncomms6646/fig_tab/ncomms6646_F3.html</file>
  <file>/ncomms/2014/141223/ncomms6646/fig_tab/ncomms6646_F4.html</file>
  <file>/ncomms/2014/141223/ncomms6646/fig_tab/ncomms6646_F5.html</file>
```

I want to delete both line which contains "appcover" and "cimage"

Coudld you pls update the code n give me? Sorry since Iam new to batch file i'm depending on your coding only.

Also If i want to edit the 10 files i cant put all xmls in one folder since the filename of the all xmls will be pushlive-manifest.xml only, all these files are stored in a their own diretories. Is any way to put this batch file in route folder adn it should read the xmls in the sub-directories with in the root folder.

Eg: route dir path is:D:/abc the xmls are in "D:/abc/123", "D:/abc/121" "D:/abc/125" and so on.

So i can place the batch file in D:/abc folder and if i run batch file it should read the xmls wch are there in "D:/abc/123", "D:/abc/121" "D:/abc/125" and so on.

Expecting your reply on this!

I changed the coding as below:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=D:\test"
FOR /r "%sourcedir%" %%a IN (pushlive-manifest*.xml) DO (
 FINDSTR /v /L "cimage.jpg appcover" "%%a" >"%%~dpna.txt"
 move /y "%%a" "%%~na"
)
GOTO :EOF
```

and as a result it is not processinfg other xmls but it just creates one txt for each xml in its dir. and the out file is not overwiting  the original xml it is still generating txt file. this time it is not creating copy of input xml to txt file where as as it is deleting the expecte dlines in the xml and converting it into txt. PLs suggest

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"
FOR %%a IN ("%sourcedir%\*.xml") DO (
 FINDSTR /v /L "cimage.gif appcover" "%%a" >"%%~dpna.txt"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

A new file is generated called *samebasename*.txt in the same directory as the directory scanned. It's not clear whether you want to delete lines that contain either `"cimage.gif" **OR**  "appcover"` or those that contain both `"cimage.gif" and "appcover"`. This code assumes the former.

---

Revision for revise requirement : search for `.xml`s in tree

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
FOR /r "%sourcedir%" %%a IN (*.xml) DO (
 FINDSTR /v /L "cimage.gif appcover" "%%a" >"%%~dpna.txt"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

Note that in the Windows world, `\` is a directory-separator and `/` is a switch-indicator. Windows often, but not always, makes the translation. Best to use the correct form.

---

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
FOR /r "%sourcedir%" %%a IN (pushlive-manifest*.xml) DO (
 FINDSTR /v /L "cimage.gif appcover" "%%a" >"%%~dpna.LMX"
 Move /y "%%~dpna.LMX" "%%~nxa"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

This should work for you - just change the directory-name as required

Comment: Thanks for all your help with this, itried and it looks fab! last one thisng is there any way to perform above task in the same input file, now I'm getting the out put as .txt file but i want the lines to be deleted in the same input file. i.e in xml format.

Comment: Batch *can* update in-place, but it's fiddly. Also, if the drive being processed is FAT not NTFS then it's possible for files to be skipped or double-processed (or so I've been informed.) Consequently, what I'd do is create `.LMX` files (not `.txt` - that's just for ease-of-loading-into-atext-editor) and then add another loop processing *.LMX files and execute a `move /y "%%a" "%%~na.xml"` to overwrite the existing `.xml`

Comment: also the command"FINDSTR /v /L "cimage.gif appcover" "%%a" >"%%~dpna.txt"" should run only for the file "pushlive-manifest.xml" file only it is executing on other xml files by result all other xmls returning to zero bytes by deleting all its contents it should not happen. only pushlive-manifest file should alter. please suggest. i tried changing the *.xml to pushlive-manifest.xml in the above command but it didn't work!

Comment: Try using `pushlive-manifest*.xml` - if the target is a single file, the entire tree apears to be processed (but appeared to single out "pushlive-manifest.xml" alone in each directory for me.) Using an `afn` (ambiguous filename) appears to force a match against the filemask. Also, on a side-note, shows the power of producing independent files (but I'll add it to my battery of things-to-be-fixed-for-W10 suggestions for Microsoft at https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/266908-command-prompt/filters/new?query=CMD.exe

Comment: I changed the coding as below: @ECHO OFF SETLOCAL SET "sourcedir=D:\test" FOR /r "%sourcedir%" %%a IN (pushlive-manifest*.xml) DO ( FINDSTR /v /L "cimage.jpg appcover" "%%a" >"%%~dpna.txt" move /y "%%a" "%%~na" ) GOTO :EOF and as a result it is not processinfg other xmls but it just creates one txt for each xml in its dir. and the out file is not overwiting the original xml it is still generating txt file. this time it is not creating copy of input xml to txt file where as as it is deleting the expected lines in the xml and converting it into txt. PLs suggest

Comment: with above mentioned coding the batch file is processing only one XML file and moves it to source dir but the sub-directories xml are reamining unchnged!